# Angular JS === comparison not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to compare the value passed from the url to a controller to a field in a json file.

galleryItem.html

```
    <div class="filter-box">
        <ul class="filter list-inline text-center" ng-repeat="gal in ParentData">
            <li><a href="Gallery/({{gal.GalleryLink}})"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="portfolio-box" ng-repeat="x in data">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="item-img-wrap">
                        <img ng-src={{x.url}} class="img-responsive" alt="">

                        <div class="item-img-overlay">
                            <a href={{x.url}} class="show-image">
                                <span></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The updated controller:

```
controllers.controller('GalleryViewCtrl', function GalleryViewCtrl($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
$scope.pageName = '';
$scope.Description = '';
$scope.GalleryID = $stateParams.id;

$http.get('/data/galleryItems.json')
                .then(function (response) { $scope.ParentData = response.data.galleries });


$http.get('/data/galleryItemImages.json')
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.data = response.data.images.galleryIdentifier === $stateParams.id;
                });
```

});

I verified the correct value is being passed in to the controller, the values are static and so is the data being passed from the json file.  I placed an if statement to check for null as suggested as well.  I removed it temporarily to reduce what I'm working with.

If I remove the === $stateParams.id i get all of the images returned and displayed correctly.

If I replace $stateParams.id with a value that I know is in the list (4 or '4') i do not get anything returned.  I also tried the value for the last item in the list.

There are no errors (loading scripts, reading json etc.) and all of the values are correct when I'm debugging.

I am still new to this and there is so much documentation with different solutions it all gets very confusing.  If anyone has any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could just add a breakpoint on that line to actually see what the values are.

Comment: Alternatively, you can ``console.log($scope.data.galleryIdentifier)`` and ``scope.GalleryID`` and compare the values manually. ``===`` is also comparing the type of the expressions, so you might want to look into that especially.

Comment: Each img has the values inserted into the html so when i do not use a filter and view all the images i can see the output is correct, or do you mean if the comparison is true or false?

Comment: Show us the HTML. When are you calling `galleryFiltered()`?

Comment: I updated my question with more of the code.  galleryFiltered is now just data and I am attempting to filter directly off the json file when the view loads instead of loading all items and then filtering them after.  I think it is possibly simpler for this project to do this.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading data to the `$scope.data` when the ajax call returns some data. I am assuming your view code is calling the `galleryFiltered` even before that. May be try to add a null check before returning the value from the method.

```
$scope.galleryFiltered = function () {
   if($scope.data!=null) 
   {
      return $scope.data.galleryIdentifier === $scope.GalleryID;
   }
   return false;
};
```

Comment: I added the if statement add tossed in some break points on the return.  There is data there, it is read to init the index portion of the gallery.  The return statement is returning over and over again however.  I think its returning individual items not the array.  Would that make sense?  Basically what I want is there is a list of photos, you click gallery 1 only the ones that have 1 in the galleryIdentifier field are shown.  But all the files not just 1 or the result of the last comparison. I am assuming this will return an array of json data just like it is reading.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $http service returns a promise so your $scope.data will be undefined (or holding current state) until `$http.get('/data/galleryItemImages.json')` will return a success callback function and assign new value to `$scope.data` from response.

If you'll run `$scope.galleryFiltered()` before promise gets resolved you will have `$scope.data == undefined` or whatever data is stored on `$scope.data` at the time or `$scope.galleryFiltered()` execution.